# Full width sub menu with pushing content down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a menu, what I am trying to achieve here is a full width sub menu whcig pushes the content on click and shows the submenu. I have a problem craeting full width sub menu and also when i click the previous menu content still shows up. here is my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/he4a0eL4/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li>link1
            <div class="sub">
                <ul>
                    <li>link1</li>
                    <li>link2</li>
                    <li>link3</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>link2
            <ul class="sub">
                <li>link1</li>
                <li>link2</li>
                <li>link3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>link3
            <ul class="sub">
                <li>link1</li>
                <li>link2</li>
                <li>link3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{margin:0;}
    #wrapper{background:#ccc;}
ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}

#nav > li
{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

.sub
{
    display:none;
    widh:100%;
}
.clear
{
clear:both;
}
.content
{
height:300px;
    background:#ff0000;
    width:100%;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nav > li", this).click(function() {
        $(this).find(".sub").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: I believe, the issue is where you dont want the menu to autoclose, when you remove the cursor? Or is it something else?

Comment: the issue is when i click on link1 the sub menu shows however when i click on link2 link2 submenu also link1 sumenu both shows up. I am trying to achieve full width sub menu on click. like a mega menu

Comment: Seems fine to me. As in when i click link1, the submenu for link1 shows and i i click on link2, link1 submenu closes and shows for link2. http://jsfiddle.net/1xd1hfdy/

Comment: Here is the sample i am trying to create http://draw.to/DcR0pa

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, maybe I'm misunderstanding your problem.
When you want full width sub menu, you just have to set the CSS property width:100%;, or don't you? Is this what you expected?

```
<div id="wrapper">
<ul id="nav">
    <li>link1
        <div class="sub">
          <ul style="float:left;width:100%;">
              <li>link1</li>
              <li>link2</li>
              <li>link3</li>
          </ul>
          <ul style="float:left;width:100%;">
              <li>link1</li>
              <li>link2</li>
              <li>link3</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>link2
        <ul class="sub">
            <li>link1</li>
            <li>link2</li>
            <li>link3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>link3
        <ul class="sub">
            <li>link1</li>
            <li>link2</li>
            <li>link3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your approach but this is what I am trying to achieve  http://postimg.org/image/96bumjezf/